# REGEXP in a where clause

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, regex

I store s3 bucket's path for files in my database. Files can be either pictures(jpg) or pdfs.

Let's suppose I have uploaded *photo.jpg* to my database via application, path will be like:

```
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801123/attachment/4510/file/1113/small/photo.jpg
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801124/attachment/4511/main/111/small/photo.jpg
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801124/attachment/4511/main/111/main
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801125/attachment/4512/file
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801126/attachment/4513/main
```

For every file, I have 2 root paths:

```
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801125/attachment/4512/file
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801126/attachment/4513/main
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801124/attachment/4511/main/111/main
```

I need to get, via `where clause` only the root = 'main'.

Example:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(path_name, '.*/', '') as col2 from seg_table limit 10;
```

The query works, I get `file, main, photo.jpg` as result.

How can I include that `regexp` in a there clause?

Example:

```
WHERE (select REGEXP_REPLACE(path_name, '.*/', '') as col2 
from seg_table) = 'main'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6d65d

There is an example. Please note the `col2` returns not only 'main'. I need it to return only main and I need to put it in a where clause. I can't use `~` operator because I will need to do something like:

```
FROM test1 t1
JOIN another_view AS s
WHERE s.full_path = substr(t1.full_path, char_pos '/file..' to get /filesuser/client/.../attachment/.../) || 'main'
```

Can't use `'/main$';` as it will give me:

```
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801124/attachment/4511/main/111/main
```

instead of

```
/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801124/attachment/4511/main
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to show sample data, and JUST sample data. And, then JUST show us what you want. Don't tell us where you want things or anything else. Just tell us the task you're trying to get done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`~` POSIX Regex Operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE)

The easy way to do this is to use the `~` operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
  ( '/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801123/attachment/4510/file/1113/small/photo.jpg' ),
  ( '/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801124/attachment/4511/main/111/small/photo.jpg' ),
  ( '/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801124/attachment/4511/main/111/main' ),
  ( '/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801125/attachment/4512/file' ),
  ( '/{s3bucket}/filesuser/client/27801126/attachment/4513/main' )
) AS t(path_name)
WHERE path_name ~ '/main$';
```

You can always be more specific with your regex..

```
WHERE path_name ~ '/filesuser/client/\d+/attachment/\d+/main$';
```